# A way to return inherited object on Future.catchError

Tags: flutter, dart

there's a way to return an inherited object from a Future's catchError callback in dart?
Like:

```
Future<Animal> fromLegNumber (int legNumber){
    var obj = repo.fromLegNumber(legNumber).then((value) {
        // do something
        return Future.value(Monkey);
    }).catchError((error){
        // do something
        return Future.value(Insect);
    });
    return obj;
}
```

Knowing that Insect and Monkey inherit from Animal.
I think the return statement from .then defines the type of obj, but I don't know how to overcome this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `Insect` and `Monkey` are classes derived from `Animal`, this should work:

```
Future<Animal> fromLegNumber (int legNumber) async {
    try {
      final value = await repo.fromLegNumber(legNumber);

      return Monkey();
    }
    catch(error) {
      return Insect();
    }
}
```

It uses `async`/`await` instead of chained calls, which is basically the same, but much simpler to get right syntactically.

Comment: I thought that try/catch statements works only for sync calls. Thanks!

Comment: Well, they work when you `await` the calls. If you don't, then it does not work.